# numpy 1D array: identify pairs of elements that sum to 0

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

My code generates numpy 1D arrays of integers. Here's an example.

```
arr = np.array([-8, 7, -5, 2, -7, 8, -6, 3, 5])
```

There are two steps I need to take with this array, but I'm new enough at Python that I'm at a loss how do this efficiently.  The two steps are:

a) Identify the 1st element of pairs having sum == 0. For arr, we have   (-8, 7, -5).

b) Now I need to find the difference in indices for each of the pairs identified in a).
     The difference in indices for (-8,8) is 5, for (7,-7) is 3, 
     and for (-5,5) is 6.

Ideally, the output could be a 2D array, something like:

```
[[-8, 5],
[ 7, 3],
[-5, 6]]
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
arr = np.array([-8, 7, -5, 2, -7, 8, -6, 3, 5])

output = list()
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)-i):
        if arr[i] + arr[i+j] == 0:
            output.append([arr[i],j])

print(output)

[[-8, 5], [7, 3], [-5, 6]]
```

I have two comments also:

1) You can transfer the list to the numpy array by `np.asarray(output)`

2) Imagine you have list `[8, -8, -8]`. If you want to calculate distance of the first pair only, you can simply add `break` after the appending procedure.

Comment: I looked at your previous question. I believe some sort of looping through list is necessary. But you can use `break` to find the single pair without looping through the whole list. In this manner you will not have to loop twice. You may even more simplify the task by using `unique`.

Comment: thanks gregoruar.   Nice solution, and I appreciate the informative comments as well!